# The Laurent series of the logarithmic derivative of a polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis

In the last line of page 389 of Remmert's Theory of Complex Functions, he States that if $p(z) = z^n + a_1z^{n-1}+\dots+a_n$ then, at least outside some large enough circle, $p'/p = n/z$ plus terms in $1/z^k$ for $k>1$. I don't see why this holds.

Comment: Most proofs I've seen of the fundamental theorem of algebra using the arvjme to principle follow by comparing the logarithmic derivative of $p$ with $n/z$ and noticing that the integral of their difference tends to zero for a large enough circle.

Comment: You are using $n$ for two different things here, the degree of $p$, and the remainder order.

Comment: Thanks, it's fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a simple division

If
$$
p(z)=z^n+a_1z^{n-1}+\dots+a_n
$$
Then
$$
p'(z)=nz^{n-1}+a_1(n-1)z^{n-2}+\dots+a_{n-1}
$$
So
\begin{align*}
\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)}
&=\frac{nz^{n-1}+a_1(n-1)z^{n-2}+\dots+a_{n-1}}{z^n+a_1z^{n-1}+\dots+a_n}\\
&=z^{-1}\frac{n+a_1(n-1)z^{-1}+\dots+a_{n-1}z^{-(n-1)}}{1+a_1z^{-1}+\dots+a_n z^{-n}}\\
&=z^{-1}[n+a_1(n-1)z^{-1}+\dots+a_{n-1}z^{-(n-1)}]\\
&\hphantom{=}\times[1+a_1z^{-1}+(a_1^2+a_2)z^{-2}+\dots]\\
&=\frac{n}{z}+O(z^{-2})
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm still not seeing the second to last step - why the invrse of the denominator equal to that polynomial on $z^{-1}$?

Comment: @FM: That is a consequence of the geometric series: $\frac{1}{1-w} = 1 + w+w^2 + \ldots = 1 + w + O(w^2)$ for small $w$.